# $(window).resize resets scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

The following bit of code isn't mine, it is out of a jQuery plugin called Blueberry.

https://github.com/marktuk/Blueberry

My issue with the code is that when

```
//bind setsize function to window resize event
$(window).resize(function(){
    setsize();
});
```

executes it resets the scroll position forcing the users browser to go back too the top.

I think this issue is only on Chrome in OSX.

I should also note that it is happening even if the window hasn't been resized and it happens after a timeout has fired.

If I uncomment setsize() it still happens, if I remove $(window).resize it stops...

Anyone have any idea why this happens and if theres a solution to the problem?

If anyone does has a solution as well then theres a issue on the Github page for Blueberry, so you could send a Pull Request with a fix.

Edit:

As requested heres the setsize function but please note that I can uncomment the setsize function and it **still** changes the scroll position.

```
var setsize = function(){
   sliderWidth = $('.slides', obj).width();
   cropHeight = Math.floor(((sliderWidth/imgRatio)/o.lineheight))*o.lineheight;
   $('.slides', obj).css({height: cropHeight});
};
```

Comment: you'll need to provide the source of `setsize`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in [blackberry's demo](http://marktyrrell.com/labs/blueberry/) in OSX Chrome, Is it working for you too? @zzzzBov, you can see the code on their [github](https://github.com/marktuk/Blueberry/blob/master/jquery.blueberry.js)

Comment: @scumah ahhh thats interesting, will have to have a gander at the code to try work out whats happening...

Answer (score -1):

So ended up fixing my problem, it was down to the fact I had height set in my  element.

Now why it was causing $(window).resize to jump back to the top of the page... I don't know!

If anyone can work it out would be awesome.